# How to get keyboard property programmatically on Android (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin

Any way to check programmatically if the keyboard "sound on press" or any other property is enabled on currently selected keyboard? Found some references to AudioManager but didn't find anything useful. Bonus points for solution that would work in Xamarin.